# Cumulative distinct count across multiple dimensions in QlikSense

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to count distinct cumulatively with two dimensions.

I have tried the below code which does work when there is only a single dimension, however this does not work with multiple dimensions.

```
Rangesum(Above(Count( distinct [FieldName]),0,RowNo()))
```

FYI - attempting this within a line chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A temporary answer to this is to remove the second dimension and amend the measure.

```
Rangesum(Above(sum( if(Dimension=1,Measure)),0,RowNo()))
```

However this does require a separate measure for each possible value in the dimension.